# How to determine the current Enhanced Zoom factor in Compiz?

Tags: bash, python, compiz

When I use Skype :( need to, rather than want to ), I find that I sometimes want to open the main menu, but it doesn't have a shortcut key assigned to it (well, not one that I can find).

I have written a bash/python script which searches for and clicks on Skype's main menu icon. This works quite well when the icon is within the screen area and when it is off-screen with a normal sized (un-zoomed) screen.

However, I cannot find a way to locate the icon so that I can move it into the zoomed screen area (so the script can send a mouse-click to it). To do this the current Compiz Enhanced Zoom factor needs to be known.

I would like to know if this value is accessible, and how?   ... and maybe; **Is** there a shortcut key for Skype's main menu? but I still want to know about the Compiz value, as the issue has come up before, and probably will again.

(using Ubuntu 10.04, compiz 0.8.4)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is enabling Compiz's DBus plugin and querying that. Unfortunately, [that plugin is broken at the moment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/749084), so this is not a solution yet.